# Wordpress Excerpt with allowable tags is not working?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create the simple excerpt plugin in Wordpress. I Googled a lot the allowable tag is not working, can anyone give me a suggestion how to do this?

```
   class fpexcerpt {

    function __construct() {
        require_once('inc/template.php');
        if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
            add_action('admin_init',array($this,'fpexcerptrestore'));
        }

    }
    function fpexcerptdefault() {
        add_option('fpexcerptcount',55);
        add_option('fpexcerptmore','[...]');
    }

    function fpexcerptrestore() {
        delete_option('fpexcerpttag');
        delete_option('fpexcerptcount');
        delete_option('fpexcerptmore');
        fpexcerpt::fpexcerptdefault();
    }

    function fpexcerptadmin() {
        add_submenu_page('options-general.php','Fantastic Excerpt', 'Fantastic Excerpt', 'manage_options','fpexcerptadmin', 'fpexcerptadmin_menu');
    }

    function fpexcerptupdate() {
        register_setting('fpexcpt','fpexcerpttag');
        register_setting('fpexcpt','fpexcerptcount');
        register_setting('fpexcpt','fpexcerptmore');
    }

    function improved_trim_excerpt($text) {
        global $post;
        if ( '' == $text ) {
                $text = get_the_excerpt();
                $text = apply_filters('the_excerpt',$text);
               // $text = str_replace('\]\]\>', ']]&gt;', $text);

                $text = strip_tags($text, '<a>');
                $excerpt_length = 80;
                $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
                if (count($words)> $excerpt_length) {
                        array_pop($words);
                        array_push($words, '[...]');
                        $text = implode(' ', $words);
                }

        }
       return $text;
    }




}
$new = new fpexcerpt();
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array('fpexcerpt','fpexcerptdefault'));
//remove_all_filters('wp_trim_excerpt');
//add_filter('get_the_excerpt', array('fpexcerpt','fpexcerptprocess'));
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt',array('fpexcerpt','wp_trim_excerpt'));
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', array('fpexcerpt','improved_trim_excerpt'));
add_action('admin_menu',array('fpexcerpt','fpexcerptadmin'));
add_action('admin_init',array('fpexcerpt','fpexcerptupdate'));
?>
```

**EDIT:**

[image: EXCERPT IMAGES]

[image: CONTENT IMAGE]

The first image is show the excerpt content when i click the particular post its getting link but not in excerpt even if i add the excerpt plugin (mine)

Comment: What does "not working" mean here? Can you supply a live link, or add screenshots?

Comment: Might have something to do with your `if ( '' == $text )` conditional. You're only catching `$text` values of empty strings.

Comment: thus i create the plugin for that its activate without error but the functionality is not getting to work for example i am going to try the <a> tag when i use the_excerpt that link cames as text indeed of link

Comment: @ Crowjonah thanks for your suggestion then what i do ?

Comment: filter that i am using is may cause this prob

Comment: @Vignesh, why aren't you using the filter `the_excerpt` instead of `the_content`?

Comment: @Spencer Cameron can you elaborate briefly pls.?

Comment: `$text = apply_filters('the_content',$text);` - why not use `$text = apply_filters('the_excerpt',$text);`?

Comment: We still need to know what **not working** means. :)

Comment: getting error    when using the_excerpt Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in E:\wamp\www\fp\wp-includes\cache.php on line 453

Answer (score 0):

Error: **Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in E:\wamp\www\fp\wp-includes\cache.php on line 453**

Based on the error you've reported above, I can surmise you're stuck in a recursive function call loop. In other words, a function you've written is ( at some point in the callstack ) calling itself ( or a function that calls it ). Picture an infinite loop, but with functions.

I can't determine where this is occurring since I can't see all of your code.

Comment: Thanks Spencer I edited My code Right Now. This is the actual code